# How do I selectively apply two CSS style blocks that have overlapping element references?

Tags: html, css

Say I have this:

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  background-color: #96D4D4;
}
```

Notice how I have these two CSS blocks, with overlapping references (they both refer to both th and td). Say I have two tables, then:

```
<table>
  <tr>
  <td>This is one table, no formatting</td>
  <tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
  <td>This is another table, to which I want to apply formatting.</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

How would I only apply the CSS style to the bottom table? Here's what I have tried so far:

**Attempt 1: Lump all the attributes into one style and put it into <div>**

```
.betterformat {
  border: thin groove blue;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: red;
}
<div class="betterformat">
  <--Here's all my <table> <tr> and <td> tags...--
</div>
```

This did not work, so then I thought

**Attempt 2: Make 2 separate classes for table and tr/td**

But no, I know that going through and setting class for each individual `<tr>` and `<td>` tag is time consuming and obviously not the way to go. For future reference, is there a good page that explains how overlapping references work in CSS, and how class interacts with it, and perhaps stuff like ID?

Comment: Any decent description of CSS selectors will explain all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the CSS [type selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) with your [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) (in your case *betterformat* :

```html
<style>
  .betterformat table,
  .betterformat th,
  .betterformat td {
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  .betterformat th,
  .betterformat td {
    background-color: #96D4D4;
  }
</style>



<table>
  <tr>
    <td>This is one table, no formatting</td>
    <tr>
</table>

<div class="betterformat">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>This is another table, to which I want to apply formatting.</td>
      <tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assign a different class to each table and then style the classes as needed:

```css
.table1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.table1 td {
  color: green;
}

.table2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.table2 td {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<table class="table1">
  <tr>
  <td>This is one table.</td>
  <tr>
</table>

<br>

<table class="table2">
  <tr>
  <td>This is another table.</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Research BEM notation.  The idea being you define a .table class that has all your base styles for a table.  You then add a modifier like .table--type1 or .table--type2 which extends or overlays the base class.